# Does Android ART assume all code is present at compile time? If so, can it make use of that for optimization?

Tags: android, compilation, jit, dalvik

The Android ART runtime is an ahead-of-time (aot) compiler, contrary to Dalvik and Hotspot which do just-in-time (jit) compiling.

One advantage of jit compilation is that it can inline methods that are not provably the right target. In code like this:

```java
public class Foo {
    public int doOperation(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}

public class Bar {
    public int doIt(int a, long repeat, Foo foo) {
        for (long i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            a = foo.doOperation(a, 1);
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

it is not generally possible to inline the `doOperation` into `doIt`, because one could create a derived class `DerivedFoo` that overrides the `doOperation` method. In the case of Java, such a `DerivedFoo` class need not be present at compile time but can be present at runtime or (on HotSpot) even be dynamically generated at runtime.

One advantage of jit compilation is that the compiler can specialize for the exact code and types that are being used, and e.g. HotSpot would be able to inline the `doOperation` call in the code above, and dynamically de-optimize if it turned out that the passed in `foo` was not a `Foo` as was assumed.

Android ART does ahead-of-time compilation, so it can not make such an optimization, unless it assumes that all code is present at compile time and sees that no other classes derive from `Foo`.

Does ART make such an assumption, and is it able to make use of that during compilation and e.g. inline the `doOperation` into `doIt` in the above code? If not, would it inline `doOperation` if it were marked `final`?